# Summarize accomplishing a condition between rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Name Start End  Feature
A    50    100   N
A    55    97    R
A    160   200   L
B    300   350   Y
B    310   350   X
B    349   370   M
```

I would like to get a new dataframe grouping this by first, second and third column, but I would like to get two new variables: one counting the number of times column A is repeates and the other counting the number of different coordinates presenting a low overlapping (say that I want less than a 20% of overlaping, calculating it as `length(overlaped_region)/mean(c(length(region1), length(region2))`.

How can I achieve that?

I've tryed:

```
newdf<- df %>% group_by(Names, Start, End) %>% summarise (count(Start), ???)
```

How can I get a column counting the number of different coordinates overlaping less than 20% for each Name?

```
Name  Count1  Count2

A       3       2
B       3       2
```

Answer (score 2):

You requested a `dplyr` solution based on the tag. I hope you don't have too many rows of data.

What you need to do this with `dplyr` is a non-equi join. The `fuzzyjoin` package offers this functionality:

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
df %>% 
  mutate(Length = 1 + End - Start) %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(., ., 
                  by = c("Name" = "Name", "ID" = "ID",
                         "Start" = "End", "End" = "Start"), 
                  match_fun = list(`==`,`!=`,`<=`,`>=`)) %>%
  mutate(Overlap = abs(pmax(Start.x,Start.y,na.rm = TRUE) - pmin(End.x,End.y,na.rm=TRUE)),
         Low = Overlap / (Length.x + Length.y)/2 < 0.2) %>%
  group_by(Name.x) %>%
  summarise(Count1 = length(unique(ID.x)), Count2 = sum(!is.na(Low) & !Low))
#  Name.x Count1 Count2
#  <fct>   <int>  <int>
#1 A           3      2
#2 B           6      2
```

A better plan would likely be to use the [`GenomicRanges`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/GenomicRanges/inst/doc/GenomicRangesIntroduction.html) package.

Comment: Thanks! What's the meaning of "ID" = "ID" ?

Comment: `"ID" = "ID"` matches `!=` in the `match_fun` argument. So it avoids joining an interval onto itself.

Comment: I get this error when I use it: ````Error: Column `col` can't be used as a grouping variable because it's a NULL````. If I remove it (`"ID" = "ID"` and `!=`) then it seems to work.

Comment: and how would you do this with GenomicRanges? Because I have quite a lot rows and this method is memory consuming